# npm FontAwesome Angular 4 compile errors

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, font-awesome

I'm using Angular CLI and trying to get Font Awesome working in my project.

I have installed Font Awesome with `npm install font-awesome --save`

I have attempted to import the library with

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

at the top of my `styles.scss`

but when running `ng-serve` I am getting the following compile errors

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/css/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0' in '/Users/MyName/Documents/Workspace/my-app/src/css'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/css/styles.css 6:181980-182057
 @ ./src/css/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/css/styles.css
```

Has anyone had similar problems? I'm trying not to mess with the `angular-cli.son` if I can help it.

Comment: Can you post your angular-cli.json config?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a lot of searching I found an answer on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues

Change 
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

Into :

@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

This is a temporary workaround do to an issue with the sass webpack plugin and should be fixed soon.

Hopefully this workaround will do it for you

Comment: Thanks @Roel Hellemons but this unfortunately didn't fix the console error from showing. I had the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the font.css into your angular-cli.json

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "styles": [
                "../nodes_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

now you can use the font awesome classes within your app

```
// in html
<i class="fa fa-close"></i>

// or within your styles
.some-class:before{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\F00D"
}
```

The angular-cli.json is your friend. Importing the font library in your angular-cli.json will let future developers of your app know where to look an easily find what style dependencies the application has.

Comment: Thanks @LLai, I have removed the reference from my styles.scss to remove the previous error and implemented as you suggested, but now have this error `ERROR in multi ./src/css/styles.css ./nodes_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/MyName/Documents/Workspace/my-app/nodes_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' in '/Users/MyName/Documents/Workspace/my-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'
 @ multi ./src/css/styles.css ./nodes_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: Just as a further note, my styles array is now:
`"styles": [
        "css/styles.css",
        "../nodes_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ],`

Comment: @DanHodson seems like webpack can't find the font awesome file. can you confirm that it exists? '/Users/MyName/Documents/Workspace/my-app/nodes_modules/font‌​-awesome/css/font-aw‌​esome.min.css'

Comment: Yes I can confirm that it is definitely there and included. I have also followed the guide from [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/include-font-awesome.md) and it's still not working as it should do.

Comment: @DanHodson odd, its a shot in the dark, but maybe something is corrupted in your node_modules folder. Can you try deleting those and reinstalling?